# Function that needs to putt limited length strings doesn't work well

Tags: c

I've got this function i created:

```
void getWords(int words){
    int remaining, error=0;
    char word[WORD_MAX+1], def[DEF_MAX+1];

    for(remaining = words;remaining > 0;remaining--){
        do{
            printf("Enter definition #%d out of %d:\n",((words+1) - remaining),words);
            gets(word);
            if(strlen(word) > WORD_MAX){
                error = 1;
                printf("\nError! '%s' contains %d characters | Maximum allowed: %d | Please try again...\n\n",word,strlen(word),WORD_MAX);
            }
        }while(error);
    }
}
```

It does what it should do basically, checks if the string length is at most 'WORD_MAX' characters long and if not asks the user to do it again,
My problem is this:

when i tested it with WORD_MAX of 3 and tried to write a 6 characters long string it works perfectly, but when i tried to write a really long string, for example 20 chars long, it wrote only some of the word, with some weird ascii smiley on the end, and the 'remaining' variable which contains the number of words i ask the function to input get some garbage value and it ruins the whole program, why does it do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, there is no way to avoid buffer overflow with `gets`.  As an alternative, you could use `fgets`

```
fgets(word, WORD_MAX+1, stdin);
```

From its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream); 
> fgets() reads in at
>   most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into
>   the buffer pointed to by s.

Comment: There is no way to prevent it using the normal gets func?

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent overflow using `gets`.  `fgets` for stream `stdin` is equivalent to `gets`, just without the overflow vulnerability.

Comment: @argamanza You can't specify a read size for `gets`. It reads up to a newline or until end-of-file, so buffer overflows are pretty much unpreventable.